# Unexpected value ' ' imported by the module ' '. Please add a @NgModule annotation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm doing this tutorial: https://youtu.be/qs2n_poLarc?list=WL and am trying to learn ionic framework.

The problem is the tutorial is (from what I read) a little outdated. Author of the video used the `import { HttpModule } from "@angular/http`, but I read on StackOverflow that I should use `import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";`.

The problem is when I try to compile the code I get this error: `Unexpected value 'HttpClient' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.`. Now I have no idea where I should add it, because my `app.module.ts` looks like this:

```
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from "@angular/core";
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { IonicApp, IonicModule, IonicErrorHandler } from "ionic-angular";
import { MyApp } from "./app.component";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";

import { AboutPage } from "../pages/about/about";
import { ContactPage } from "../pages/contact/contact";
import { HomePage } from "../pages/home/home";
import { TabsPage } from "../pages/tabs/tabs";
import { SettingsPage } from "../pages/settings/settings";

import { StatusBar } from "@ionic-native/status-bar";
import { SplashScreen } from "@ionic-native/splash-screen";
import { WeatherProvider } from "../providers/weather/weather";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    AboutPage,
    ContactPage,
    HomePage,
    TabsPage,
    SettingsPage
  ],
  imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp), HttpClient], //Added it right here
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    AboutPage,
    ContactPage,
    HomePage,
    TabsPage,
    SettingsPage
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler },
    WeatherProvider,
    HttpClient
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Any idea what I'm missing here? I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47109411/unexpected-value-imported-by-the-module-please-add-a-ngmodule-annotation) answer but I cannot find the solution there.

Comment: did the answer help ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It means it doesn't recognise it as a module. Try this:

```
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
```

Comment: So it was just a problem with the name?

Comment: @alex3wielk - yes, looks like Angular team renamed module. I checked in docs. Wonder why someone down-voted... :|

Comment: :O it was by mistake just now i realized that! i was doing that from a phone ! i actually upvoted you since you've added the correct import part. my sincere appologies. since i cannot upvote this again i will upvote one of your other answer

Answer (score 8):

It should be **`HttpClientModule`** , Change,

From

```
imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp), HttpClient],
```

To

```
imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp), HttpClientModule],
```

make sure you've added

```
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace **`HttpClient`** with **`HttpClientModule`** and don't change `import` part.
Because **`HttpClientModule`**  access many part of **`HttpClient`**.